# Get Local Phone Number Objective-C For Validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, phone-number

I need the get Sim card phone number from iphone for validate the number.How can I do that ?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question?  I think it is a bit difficult to understand as written.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. To validate a phone number the best option is to use a third party service (like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com)) and send an SMS with a verification code or verification URL. You can then validate the user is able to receive SMS to the number.